# angular 2 - ngx-pipes error module

Tags: angular

ERROR in C:/.../node_modules/ngx-pipes/node_modules/@angular/core/src/errors.d.ts (9,33): Initializers are not allowed in ambient contexts.

i cant start my npm...

ERROR in Error encountered resolving symbol values statically. Calling function 'ɵmakeDecorator', function calls are not supported.

Consider replacing the function or lambda with a reference to an exported function, resolving symbol NgModule in C:/.../node_modules/ngx-pipes/node_modules/@angular/core/core.d.ts, resolving symbol NgPipesModule in

C:/.../node_modules/ngx-pipes/src/app/pipes.module.ts, resolving symbol NgPipesModule in C:/.../node_modules/ngx-pipes/src/app/pipes.module.ts

Comment: npm -v 4.2.0
node -v 7.6.0

Comment: "@angular/cli": "^1.0.0-beta.28.3",
    "@angular/common": "^2.3.1",
    "@angular/compiler": "^2.3.1",
    "@angular/core": "^2.3.1",
    "@angular/forms": "^2.3.1",
    "@angular/http": "^2.3.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^2.3.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^2.3.1",
    "@angular/router": "^3.3.1",